# How to create nextjs app without github repository

Tags: next.js

So I have a repo for my project and I want to create a next 13 app for the frontend. How should I go about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for nothing. The reason I asked is that it's not mentioned in the docs, nor in the help.

`npx create-next-app@latest . --no-git`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run `npx create-next-app@latest`. You don't need a github repository to create a project